# In Flutter Go_Router, the replace command to use routing to ShellRoute is not working properly

Tags: flutter, nested-routes, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to make a application that have a init page and nested routed page.

To do that, I use a `go_router` library.

Here is my code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> rootNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> shellNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: rootNavKey,
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(child: Home()),
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: shellNavKey,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/somepage1',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(child: SomePage1()),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/somepage2',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(child: SomePage2()),
        ),
      ],
      builder: (context, state, child) => Shell(state: state, child: child),
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

class Shell extends StatelessWidget {
  Shell({super.key, required this.state, required this.child}) {
    print('Shell: ${state.location}');
  }

  final GoRouterState state;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () => context.go('/somepage1'),
                  title: const Text('Go to SomePage 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () => context.go('/somepage2'),
                  title: const Text('Go to SomePage 2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: child),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => context.replace('/somepage1'),
          child: const Text('Click!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomePage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomePage1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Some Page 1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SomePage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomePage2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Some Page 2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you clicked the text in the init page, you can go to the nested page that I want to go - somepage1.

But there are some strange point have a gap with my purpose.

My purposes are these.

1. When I go to nested page, the nested page have to be an only page.
2. When the nested page was built, the parent widget **Shell** have to be built also.

But these two purposes are not satisfied.

1. When I went to nested page, the previous page was not popped.
2. When the nested page was build, the parent widget **Shell** was not built.

To solve this issue, what should I do...?

Comment: I have faced this too. It's quite strange behavior. Have written a bug report at GitHub?

Comment: @Abigotado i check lately sorry. No, i didn't. i just gave up using the ```ShellRouter```